# How do you install a module from github?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

```
import sys
sys.path.append('05_com')
from BSM_option_valuation import BSM_call_value

def d1f(St, K, t, T, r, sigma):

    ''' Black-Scholes-Merton d1 function.
    Parameters see e.g. BSM_call_value function. '''

 d1 = (math.log(St / K) + (r + 0.5 * sigma ** 2)
        * (T - t)) / (sigma * math.sqrt(T - t))
return d1
```

I am learning to plot a BSM graph (Black-Scholes-Merton model),however, I am not too sure how to install the module that was uploaded in github. Seeking for any advice please.

Link: https://github.com/buswedg/MSPA/blob/master/PREDICT%20400/Weekly%20Discussion/W6%20Derivates/BSM_option_valuation.py

Answer (score 2):

Go inside of that particular Github repository . Click on the option 'Code' , Then copy the url . After that come to you terminal and write

```
git clone <copied url>
```